# Android changed app_name string, now it crashes

Tags: android, string, android-activity, crash, program-entry-point

I've changed text in the app_name string (just wanted to fix the spelling).
When I ran the project it returned a disaster:

```
11-15 18:20:13.181: W/dalvikvm(926): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dreamoholic.android.smartshoppinglist/com.dreamoholic.android.smartshoppinglist.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.dreamoholic.android.smartshoppinglist.Main.onCreate(Main.java:127)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-15 18:20:13.211: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  ... 11 more
```

I have tried to undo the spelling but couldn't fix the problem anymore.
I've done this once, but it worked when I changed back the text.

I've looked at the 127. line in Main.java and commented out that onClickListener, but than it just goes to another line and gives an error there.

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dreamoholic.android.smartshoppinglist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Saved"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".List"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, Main!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Smart Shopping List</string>
    <!-- strings for Main top row -->
    <string name="main_new">New</string>
    <string name="main_popular">Popular</string>
    <string name="main_saved">Saved</string>
    <string name="main_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem.
I've tried to copy the project, clean it and copy it by hand into another new project.

I have messed up my package names on creating a new project.
Now I've checked all package names and they are consistent.

First I get an error on my 127. line that is:

```
            tv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Comment: check whether the package name in activity or everywhere else is same or not..! also for in gen folder check..!

Comment: you are referencing something with the wrong name.

Comment: I'm somewhat sure renaming that string isn't the actual issue. Please post the code snippet where the stacktrace gets thrown.

Comment: try adding full package names for the activites like android:name="com.android.smartshoppinglist.Main"

Comment: Your package name in manifest is `com.android.smartshoppinglist` , but the error seems to try to call `com.dreamoholic.android.smartshoppinglist`; please change, and clean the project.

Comment: The package name was my copy paste mistake.. sorry. I've added the code where returns an error

Comment: Sorry everybody! Thaks for your efort! I've found that I had a SharedPreference with no default value, set to an IF clause where the layout xml is initialised, and there was no ELSE clause! Silly me! Sorry again for all the trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you used your appname or packege name hardcoded in your project - folders, databases, content providers, custom controlos etc. What I would do in your case is to search the old value in the whole project (Ctrl + H, FileSearch tab) and look is there something wrong.

Edit: uninstalling the application from the device/emulator is required too (or clear the user data, but I prefer the complete uninstall).

Comment: I've checked package names. But I'm shure that it worked before I've changed the app_name string. No old string comes up with the search.

Comment: just one thing - did you uninstall the application from the device/emulator? If not - try it

Comment: Yes I did uninstall it. I lost saved SharedPreferences and had no default value set, so it blew in my face! :) fixed it now.. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try following

- clean up your project (Project -> Clean)
- right click your project -> Android Tools -> Fix project properties

I have found out that sometimes the R file is not rebuild and this helps.